# StreamResult parameter type in RavenDB query

Tags: java, indexing, ravendb

I took an [example](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/java/client-api/session/querying/how-to-stream-query-results) from the RavenDB documentation, and adapted it to fit the types I am working with in my code. The type I am using is known (it can be resolved), and the query targets a predefined index. The query uses the spatial option, if that has any part to play in this.

In Eclipse, no matter what type I use for T in this: `CloseableIterator<StreamResult<T>>` - the error message is always "The type StreamResult is not generic; it cannot be parameterised with arguments <*whatever*>".
As I'm still quite new to RavenDB, this may well be something obvious that I'm missing. 
The type I am working with is a POJO, and consists exclusively of Strings, int and floats. 
If you require more info on the index or the type, please let me know.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay close attention to your imports ! In my case, it was a simple case of adding the wrong import - because I clicked too fast without verifying that it was the correct library (Eclipse suggested something and I just accepted). It should have been the second option:

```
net.ravendb.abstractions.data.StreamResult
```

and NOT

```
javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
```

which was first in the list of suggested fixes.

Comment: Could you mark it as the correct answer so others can find it please ? Thank you !

Comment: @sasuke256, of course. Stackoverflow won't let me accept my own answer in less than 2 days, though. I'll mark it tomorrow.